# EGLImages with renderbuffer as source sibling and texture as target sibling

Tags: android, linux, opengl-es, egl

I am trying to setup an `EGLImage` where the source sibling is a `GL_RENDERBUFFER` (the `EGLClientBuffer` specified as an argument to `eglCreateImageKHR`). In another context, I create a `GL_TEXTURE_2D` and specify it as the target sibling of the `EGLImage` by using `glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES`. Unfortunately, the latter call leads to a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. If both the source and target siblings are `GL_TEXTURE_2D`'s, the setup works like a charm.

From my reading of the specification, this should be a permissable operation. It is also possible that my reduced test case has some other orthogonal issue. Though I doubt this since the setup works fine when both the source and target siblings are `GL_TEXTURE_2D`'s. However, if this were the issue (and this kind of usage of `EGLImage`s was permissable), what could be the possible issue that may lead to to a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. Or am I just mistaken in my interpretation of the specification?

Referenced Extensions:

http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_EGL_image.txt

http://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/extensions/KHR/EGL_KHR_image_base.txt

Clarifications:

- I do check for the presence of all extensions in the specification (`EGL_KHR_image`, `EGL_KHR_image_base`, `EGL_KHR_gl_texture_2D_image`, `EGL_KHR_gl_renderbuffer_image`, etc..).
- I also realize that there may be differences in the internal format of the EGLImage when I am using a `GL_RENDERBUFFER` vs a `GL_TEXTURE_2D` as the source. So I tried using the `OES_EGL_image_external` extension first with the texture as the source and then the renderbuffer. The texture works fine as always, the same `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` for the renderbuffer. Using external images when binding makes no difference to the error generated.
- Both GL and EGL errors are checked after each call.

Comment: depending on your platform, some egl extension could be missing, check for it with `QueryString(dpy, EGL_EXTENSIONS);`

Comment: @j-p I amended the original question with some clarifications. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a lot more time on this and `EGLImage`'s in general after running into this issue. [alonorbach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3591277/alonorbach)'s hypothesis was correct.

If for any reason, the driver cannot create a texture sibling from the supplied `EGLImage`, then a rather ambiguous `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is returned. I was under the impression that if I was able to create a valid `EGLImage` (i.e., not an `EGL_NO_IMAGE_KHR`) and the appropriate extensions were supported, I would be able to bind to the same using either a rendebuffer or texture sibling (in `GL_OES_EGL_image`). This is certainly *not* the case. It also seems to vary a lot from device to device. I was able to get this working on `NVidia Tegra` units but not on the `Adreno 320`.

Does this mean it is impossible to reliably use EGLImages on `Android`? Not quite. Specifically for the issue I was running into, I was able to bind a texture sibling to an `EGLImage` created using a renderbuffer source by specifying `GL_RGBA8_OES` in extension `GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8` as the internal format of the source renderbuffer (argument 2 to `glRenderbufferStorage`). This is less than ideal but proves the point that somehow the internal formats of the source and target siblings must match, and, in case of a mismatch, the driver is under no obligation to accomodate the variation and is free to give up.

Another source of entropy when trying to use `EGLImage`s successfully (at least generically on `Android`) is the way in which the `EGLImage`s themselves are created. I found that it was far more reliable to create an `EGLImage` using the `EGL_NATIVE_BUFFER_ANDROID` target specified in the `EGL_ANDROID_image_native_buffer` extension. If such extensions are available for your platform, it is highly advisable to use them in a fallback manner.

In summary, the solution that seems to work reliably for me seems to be to first try and create a valid `EGLImage` using any and all available extensions in a fallback manner. Then using that `EGLImage` try binding to the target sibling kind. If this pair of operations yields no errors, then that EGLImage/TargetKind pair is supported on that device and can be used for subsequent operations. If either operation fails, the next item in the fallback chain is checked. If all else fails, a solution that does not use `EGLImage`s should likely be present. I have not encountered such an Android device yet (fingers crossed)

I am still discovering corner cases and optimizations and will keep this answer updated with findings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this could be a legitimate failure point. A `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error can arise if the driver is unable to create a texture from the EGLImage supplied.

http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_EGL_image.txt

> If the GL is unable to specify a texture object using the supplied
>   eglImageOES  (if, for example,  refers to a multisampled
>   eglImageOES), the error INVALID_OPERATION is generated.

Do you call `glFramebufferRenderbufferOES` with the renderbuffer before passing it to `eglCreateImageKHR`? If so, suggest you try tweaking how your create your renderbuffer (e.g. try a different format, size) to pin down what conditions get you this error.

Comment: I do in fact call `glFramebufferRenderbufferOES` before creating the `EGLImage`. In fact, framebuffer completeness checks pass before I create the `EGLImage` with the renderbuffer as the source sibling.


I think you are right about the failure condition however. I modified the `glRenderbufferStorage` call. If the color renderable format is `GL_RGBA4` or (unsurprisingly) any of the depth or stencil renderable formats, the creation of the `EGLImage` itself fails. In case of `GL_RGB565` or `GL_RGB5_A1`, the creation succeeds but `glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES` fails.

Comment: I only have a few more hours to award the bounty. Think your hypothesis is correct. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help. Would be interested to know if you're able to reproduce this on a different implementation, as it sounds like a painful failure condition. Please do update if you get any further solving it.

Comment: alonorbach: I have added an answer with my findings. Thanks for your help.